# Need help in constructing HashMap of String Key with Map of Strings

Tags: hashmap

I have the list of projects(String) and respective users which I am taking from users as an input :

Project1,User1
Project1,User2
Project1,User3
Project2,User4
Project2,User5

I would like to have this data in the format like:

Project1: User1,User2,User3
Project2:User4,User5

I am trying the same thing to put in hashmap

```
HashMap<String, HashSet> hsp = new HashMap<String, HashSet>();


HashSet<String> userHash = new HashSet<String>();
```

Can any one help me to understand how to do it? I am accepting both project name and user name from user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize HashMap and HashSet as follows

```
    HashSet<String> hashset=new HashSet<String>();
    HashSet<String> hashset2=new HashSet<String>();
    HashMap<String, HashSet> hashmap=new HashMap<String, HashSet>();
```

Now add elements to hashset

```
    hashset.add("User1");
    hashset.add("User2");
    hashset.add("User3");

    hashset2.add("User4");
    hashset2.add("User5");
```

Finally add HashSet to  HashMap

```
    hashmap.put("project1", hashset);
    hashmap.put("project2", hashset2);
```

So your desired o/p will be as follows

```
    Hash map is {project2=[User4, User5], project1=[User3, User2, User1]}
```